# Android studio 2.2.2.0 not running

Tags: android-studio

After reinstalling android studio it suddenly does not work anymore. It did work before but now it gets stuck on this screen.

[image]

i have added JAVA_HOME variable and added "disable.android.first.run=true" to the idea.properties but both didn't work..

my Java version is "1.8.0_111"
android studio version 2.2.2.0

It already consumed half of my day, help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

please try to add a `JDK_HOME` environment variable to your system variables. It should contain the path to your JDK's ROOT directory. like: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.xxx\